# Do PMML Models allow for singular prediction based on multiple rows of data (f.e. by aggregation?)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pmml

I'm looking for a way to apply some aggregation methods within a PMML model (with no specific example, just to see if it is possible)

In the documentation of [PMML Transformations page](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/Transformations.html#xsdElement_Aggregate) there is a passage on Aggregate, defined as a way to apply six functions: Count, Sum, Avg, Min, Max and Multiset.

[Aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0m10.png)

Does this mean that there is a way to generate a transformation inside a PMML model that will be able to collapse multiple rows of input data into a singular row of prediction? I was unable to find such an example (or any example at all), while [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380005/export-spark-feature-transformation-pipeline-to-a-file) states that only singular row operations are supported within PMML.

Searching further, the Sklearn2PMML Library has an "Aggregator" method, but this only generates a transformation within a single row, like getting an average out of two columns.

This code:

```
iris_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
    ("mapper", DataFrameMapper([
        (["Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length"], [ContinuousDomain(), Aggregator(function = "mean")]),
    ])),
])
```

Is able to generate a simple transformation, instead of Aggregate function.

```
<TransformationDictionary>
    <DerivedField name="avg(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
        <Apply function="avg">
            <FieldRef field="Sepal.Length"/>
            <FieldRef field="Petal.Length"/>
        </Apply>
    </DerivedField>
</TransformationDictionary>
```

TL;DR:

Example of what I would like to achieve:

[image: Example of what I would like to achieve]

Is there any way to do it inside the PMML model, or should I try to generate such preprocessing actions before applying the data for prediction?

Answer (score 0):

> Do PMML Models allow for singular prediction based on multiple rows of data (f.e. by aggregation?)?

Not by design - the PMML standard is about representing statistical and data mining models, not [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).

Perhaps there's another standard for ETL, which could be combined with PMML to make for an all-encompassing data application.